# Angular 7 - Highcharts title not changing

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a `Highchart` in my angular component like this:

```
highcharts = Highcharts;

    pieChartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: "pie",
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'TRPs by Daypart',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          align: 'left'
      },
     },
        xAxis: {
          title: {
            text: this.xAxis.name
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: "Reach"
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: this.xAxis.name,
            data: this.xAxis.data
          }
        ]
     };
```

then in my `.html`:

```
<highcharts-chart
 [Highcharts] = "highcharts"
 [options] = "pieChartOptions"
 style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>
```

the problem here is that the title text is not changing I only see "Chart Title" not the title text I've defined on my component. Is there anything I'm missing?

Also: Is there any way to remove the highcharts.com text on the bottom right corner?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the `title` in a wrong level, it should be outside the `chart`

```
pieChartOptions = {
  chart: { ... },
  title: { text: 'TRPs by Daypart', ... },
}
```

Regarding the removal of *highcharts.com* you can remove it by modifying `credits` option:

```
pieChartOptions = {
  chart: { ... },
  credits: {
      enabled: false
  }
}
```

I suggest you to check the [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) for whole documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Title showed up when I tried to put the title option like this (same level as chart option):

```
highcharts = Highcharts;

    pieChartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: "pie"
     },
     title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'TRPs by Daypart',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          align: 'left'
      },
...
```